# JHipster: Blank page after Facebook social login through Okta

Tags: jhipster, okta

I have created a project with JHipster v5.7.2 with authenticationType oauth2.

After configuring social login successfully with Facebook and Google I can now login. But after the Facebook login I get a blank screen and I am not forwarded to the Home page.
The console log in browser has a routing error:

```
ERROR Error: "Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '_'
```

But the Google login works fine and I am forwarded successfully to the Home page.

Comment: please share the related code.

Comment: "Any routes", u check the router file of this component?

Comment: I have not added any code to the project yet. It is just a standard generated JHipster project. All I have done is to add some configuration after following the instruction from this small tutorial: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/02/19/add-social-login-to-spring-boot